# Make react router work with spring endpoints

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring, reactjs

I have a spring boot app which provides a bunch of endpoints.

For the static resources, I use the build result of a React project.

I'm trying to configure the spring web security in a way that:

1. All requests to `/api/**` except for the requests to `/api/auth/**` must be authenticated
2. Every `GET` request made to the server, that doesn't target `/api/**` or is not authenticated must be responded with `index.html` content.

I'm using the following web security config code in my Spring boot project:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

/*
 * Apparently, permitAll() doesn't work for custom filters, therefore we ignore the signup and login endpoints 
 * here
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web)
        throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/**")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**");
}
```

How can I meeth these two requirments ? or a better question, is this a good approach? Is there a way to serve the REST API endpoints on a different port than what static resources are served on ? Is it better to start two servers (one Node server serving the front-end, one Java app server serving the REST endpoints, each one listening on different ports)?

Comment: have you managed to configure the spring-boot in the way you described?

Answer (score 0):

hm, what about creating own instances of the listening backend and "renegotiate" new ports to the clients to keep a connection alive.

If you have an handshake ...

if the ports rotate...

it would enhance the security in my point of view.

porthandling would be then part of the authentification process.

makes it harder to missuse "static" ports?

hey are you still you?

yes sure?

what was the last 3 ports hash with my salty piece?

ärrrmm ..

23?